# 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: typescript, next.js

```
'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component
```

the error is inside of _app.tsx file of nextjs.
Since yesterday I am trying to solve this problem which I got during deployment in vercel in my nextjs-typescript app. but could not solve it. this error suddenly happened and it's not from my side. any idea?

```
./pages/_app.tsx:76:14
Type error: 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<{}, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<{}, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<{}, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/vercel/path0/node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  74 |               headersData={headerData}
  75 |             />
> 76 |             <Component {...pageProps} />
     |              ^
  77 |             <Footer />
  78 |           </main>
  79 |         </Provider>
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

here is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Adding resolutions and overrides in the package.json file fixed the issue for me.

`"resolutions": {
        "@types/react": "^17.0.1",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.2"
    },
    "overrides": {
        "@types/react": "^17.0.1",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.2"
    }`

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: This happened to me today. It seems to be related to switching to yarn workspaces and turbo. Adding the resolutions and overrides didn't seem to fix it.  If I eliminate the yarn workspace things seem to work properly. Trying to sort through the fallout now...

Comment: @CodeManiak, I have a same problem as you. The error appeared when I switched to yarn workspaces. Any fixes yet? Thank you.

Comment: @Scarass I did figure it out to an extent. I had one of my modules in the workspace pointing to 17.0.38. I moved that one down to 17.02. I also used the overrides. I used `yarn cache clean`. I wiped all of my node_modules, .next, .turbo, directories. I may have even had to reclone the project at one point. Eventually I got it working. There are some confused dragons deep under the hood somewhere... never got a perfect answer.

Comment: I would also double check that you don't have this warning:

```
warning Pattern ["next@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/vercel/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-next-12.1.5-7a07687579ddce61ee519493e1c178d83abac063-integrity/node_modules/next" as pattern ["next@^12.0.8","next@^12.0.8","next@^12.0.8","next@^12.0.8"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
```

I switched to use a specific version of next `next@latest` to `^12.0.8` and it fixed some other errors. I suspect it may have also caused this bug.

Comment: Thanks @CodeManiak. I just got mine working by updating @types/react and @types/react-dom. I didn't had to use resolutions and overrides.

Comment: Ridwan Bin Sarwar's solution worked for me.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you have to use the **Layout**, like below:

```js
import React from "react";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Nav from "./Nav";

export default function Layout({children}){

    return(
        <>
        <Nav />
        <main>
            {children}
        </main>
        <Footer />
        </>
    )
}
```

and import it to the `_app.jsx` file

`_app.jsx` :

```js
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import '../css/global.css'
import Head from "next/head";


export default function ({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Head>
                <title>title</title>
            </Head>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
    )
}
```